# How to animate selected paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p>This is original paragraph. </p>
<p>Click me to see it fade.</p>
```

I want to animate second paragraph in the above HTML code.
I have tried this below jQuery Code.

```
$( "p" ).eq(2).click(function() {
  $( this ).fadeTo( 0.40 );
});
```

Comment: `:2nd` — Where did you get that syntax from?

Comment: you are looking for `:eq` selector. https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: @Sushil I've rolled back your edit.  It's not a good idea to make corrections to code in a question, as the thing you're changing may be the source of the problem the person is asking about in the first place.

Comment: I got it @DanielBeck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an equivalent method use `class` or `data-attr` method. `:eq()` method in a dynamic system mightn't work as expected. Please try this method and leave a response comment if it doesn't work.

```js
$( "p.animate-me").click(function() {
  $( this ).fadeTo("slow", 0.40 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is original paragraph. </p>
<p class="animate-me">Click me to see it fade.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:nth-child(childNo)` for getting the child at index
`fadeTo` takes two arguments `fadeTo(duration,opacity)`;

```
$( "p:nth-child(2)" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).fadeTo(1, 0.40 );
});
```